# Advanced regular expressions to handle partial French addresses

Tags: javascript, regex

My input is likethis: "78003 Versailles CEDEX 3 - France". Here 78003 is the zip code, Versailles is the city, CEDEX 3 is an optional part and means that this is a special address.

Currently my regex gets the zip code, city and country, but I can't get the CEDEX part. I guess I'm tricked by a greedy expression but I don't know how to get over it.

```
var parseZipCityAndCountryRe = /(\d*)\s*(.*)(?:\s*CEDEX\s*(\d*))?\s*-\s*(.*)/i;
parseZipCityAndCountryRe.exec("78003 Versailles cedex 120 - France") 

// current output
["78003 Versailles cedex 120 - France", "78003", "Versailles cedex 120 ", undefined, "France"]
//  wished output
["78003 Versailles cedex 120 - France", "78003", "Versailles", "120", "France"]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make the `CEDEX` group non-optional

```
var parseZipCityAndCountryRe = /(\d*)\s*(.*)(?:\s*CEDEX\s*(\d*))\s*-\s*(.*)/i;
//                                                              ^
```

or make the `.*` repetition [non-greedy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#greedy):

```
var parseZipCityAndCountryRe = /(\d*)\s*(.*?)(?:\s*CEDEX\s*(\d*))\s*-\s*(.*)/i;
//                                         ^
```

to get the desired result.

Comment: I didn't knew this non greedy option, I accept your answer since it's the most complete. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Simply convert the greedy `.*` to non greedy `.*?` in the first capture.

```
var parseZipCityAndCountryRe = /(\d*)\s*(.*?)(?:\s*CEDEX\s*(\d*))?\s*-\s*(.*)/i;
```

What is happening is that `.*` is capturing too much and is capturing 'cedex 120' as well.

Answer (score 0):

Make the capturing of the city non-greedy:

```
var parseZipCityAndCountryRe = /(\d+)\s+(.+?)\s*(cedex \d+)? - (\w+)/i;
```